# Gitlab CI - unique build number

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there any unique number in Gitlab CI which can be used as build number as we use in Jenkins. I came to know about the variable "CI_PIPELINE_IID" but the problem with this variable is, it updates for all branches and there is no such variable exist for each branch.

Answer (score 18):

We solved the same issue using the variable `$CI_PIPELINE_IID`, which is defined as

> The project-level IID (internal ID) of the current pipeline. This ID is unique only within the current project.

And is quite similar to Jenkins' `$BUILD_NUMBER`

See also https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference

Comment: How do you actually use that variable? That link defines a bunch of variables, but I don't see how to actually use it anywhere.

Comment: @Pigpocket those variables will be available in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file: you can use them in that file and GitLab will replace the variables with their actual values.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like `CI_COMMIT_SHA` or `CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` are great candidates for this as they give you a reference to the commit it was built from.

For example, if you want to use it as a docker image tag, use

```
docker build . -t myapp:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

Note that earlier versions of Gitlab (version 8.x) use `CI_BUILD_TAG`

More variables on: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't have reproducible builds you'll want this PLUS the build number ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any of the other ids "[CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/)" might work in your case:

- `CI_JOB_ID`   9.0     all     The unique id of the current job that GitLab CI uses internally
- `CI_PIPELINE_ID`  8.10    all     The unique id of the current pipeline that GitLab CI uses internally (one I)
- `CI_PROJECT_ID`   all     all     The unique id of the current project that GitLab CI uses internally
- `CI_RUNNER_ID`    8.10    0.5     The unique id of runner being used

Comment: I have already gone through the default variables and i don't think such kind of variables exist. Just wanted to know if there are any work around to have a unique number for each branches instead of repository.

Comment: @Prasa2166 OK. Not to my knowledge though.

Comment: Is CI_JOB_ID unique across all pipelines for all projects or only within the context of a single project? And similarly what about uniqueness scope for CI_PIPELINE_ID?

Comment: @dragonsfire It seems global (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/3691#note_33364475)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,it's a reasonable request for many situations. Someone has issued it before, please refer to: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/23844. But it seems that it has not added this so far.