# template yaml for backstage - is there a built-in variable that can generate set of numbers similar to uuid?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, backstage

This is very specific to Backstage. Is there some built-in variable such as $RANDOM or uuid generator that can work with fetch:template?

Thank you

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114916/2986344?
`CI_JOB_ID` or some combination with build number..

Comment: i tried but that didn't work for backstage template. I think that only works if you place that for gitlab ci yaml.

Answer (score 1):

I had used ${{range(1000)|random}} and that works